# Pasar el resultado de un comando remoto a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Para la linea de comandos en linux, me encuentro con el siguiente problema, hay varios comandos que quiero ejecutar remotamente con ssh por ejemplo

ssh root@X.X.X.X "free -h -t"

En automático sale la salida del comando free, como hago para que ese resultado se guarde en una variable y posterior ese resultado quiero ocuparlo para guardarlo como imagen

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres como "guardarlo como imagen"? y ¿Qué es lo que has investigado para resolver tu problema?

Comment: bueno la parte de la imagen ya la tengo resulta con imagemagick con el comando convert

Comment: Por ejemplo el resultado de poner free -m -t - h puede quedar de esta forma myvar=$(free -m -h -t) al colocarlo en el convert quedaria asi  ---->   convert label:"$(myvar)" mycomando.png

Comment: tienes código de ejemplo para lo que quieres hacer? muéstranos que tienes

Comment: OK explico Por una extraña razon un jefe me pidio datos de varios servidores en linux me pidio memoria y disco duro usados para un reporte es decir usar los comandos free y df y a su vez mandanar un screenshot del resultado bueno se me ocurrio que si ponia todo en un script podria al menos tener las capturas de pantalla y ya solo ir pegando en el excel

Comment: entonces uso lo siguiente sshpass -p PASSWORD root@10.10.10.X "free -m -h -t && df -h"  ---> este resultado pasarlo a variable y colocarlo en el convert que antes mencione  cabe clarar que son como 30 servidores y el reporte tengo que entregarlo cada semana

Answer (score 3):

Realiza los siguientes comandos:

```
nano varParticiones.sh
```

Acá te va abrir un archivo de texto con un extensión bash **(.sh)**, ingresas la siguiente línea de código y guardas los cambios con **Ctrl + X**

```
#! /bin/bash
#Creo una variable llamada varParticion donde ingreso cualquier comando:
varParticion=$(ssh root@10.X.X.X "free -h -t")
#Imprimo la variable varParticion
echo 'Estado de las particiones: ' $varParticion
```

Finalmente le das los permisos de ejecución al archivo **varParticiones.sh**:

```
chmod +x varParticiones.sh
```

Poner a correr tu script y listo, este es el resultado:

```
./varParticiones.sh
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que ya sabes como convertir en una imagen, de ahora en adelante tu reto es organizarlas para que se vean como quieras, ya tienes tu comando **ssh root@X.X.X.X "free -h -t"** en una variable.

Si lo que requieres es automatizarlo debes crear un bucle y que la **ip** sea una variable, y ya lo pones que recorra **n** cantidad de **ip** y ya le cambias el nombre a cada variable con su respectiva **ip**.

Espero sea de gran ayuda y puedes continuar con tu proyecto.